# MS Word Styled Tabled using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, ms-word, apache-poi

I'm working on a small project where I need to create a dynamically produced table in MS word using Java. I've been fiddling around with Apache POI, and while i'm fairly certain this is the right API for the job, i'm having a hard time finding documentation/examples for styling my table. I don't need a complex table, but I need at least to be able to change the individual column widths, margins, border types, etc.

It seems to me that there is a lot more table functionality in the XSSF (Excel) portion of POI.. would it make more sense to try and produce the table in excel and then export it to MS Word?

My other thought was to create the actual table in MS Word and then somehow reproduce the XML using POI but i'm not the most experienced programmer and this way seemed like it would be fairly complex.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Is your target a binary doc or xml-based docx?

Comment: An XML-based Docx. I've actually moved on to docx4java, as it seems more comprehensive and more fit for the project at hand. Maybe you've heard of it? ;)

Comment: Jason, if you get a chance I posted a question under the forums on your site (rightAlign). Thanks again.